# Angular: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am running a ngrx hello world from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxnq1g which is running pretty well.

However downloading the project into local, `npm install` & `npm run start`, it does not work..

It is throwing:

```
➜  angular-ngrx npm run build

> nlrxbbygykj.angular@0.0.0 build /Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx
> ng build

Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at __read (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:174:50)
    at Object.__spread (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:193:28)
    at Renderer.renderAdjacentStatements (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/renderer.js:159:63)
    at /Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/renderer.js:80:52
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Renderer.renderFile (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/renderer.js:76:46)
    at /Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/renderer.js:53:84
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Renderer.renderProgram (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/renderer.js:48:54)
    at Transformer.transform (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/transformer.js:84:42)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:195:27)
    at /Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:55:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:293:57)
    at step (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at /Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/will/Documents/Node/angular-ngrx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:287:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "/private/var/folders/10/zlppkg794_x8shqsklqs_9rc0000gn/T/ng-Ub1Ik1/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nlrxbbygykj.angular@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nlrxbbygykj.angular@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

No error during `npm install` process...
Changing the tsconfig.json doesn't work as well..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using old nodejs version?

Comment: I am using node `v12.18.3`, npm is `6.14.6`

Comment: @WillHu Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Ah.. Yes. it's resolved, long time ago. The version issue.